# Two Parent Table One Child Table Relationship

Tags: sql-server, relationship

```
PurchaseMaster

InvNo       varchar(50) (PK)
InvDate     DateTime
NetAmount   decimal(18,2)


PurchaseDetail

InvNo       varchar(50) (FK)
InvDate     DateTime
Quantity    decimal(18,2)
Rate        decimal(18,2)
Amount      decimal(18,2)
```

***PK-FK Relationship= PurchaseMaster.InvNo=>PurchaseDetail.InvNo

```
SaleMaster

InvNo       varchar(50) (PK)
InvDate     DateTime
NetAmount   decimal(18,2)

SaleDetail

InvNo       varchar(50) (FK)
InvDate     DateTime
Quantity    decimal(18,2)
Rate        decimal(18,2)
Amount      decimal(18,2)
```

***PK-FK Relationship= SaleMaster.InvNo=>SaleDetail.InvNo

```
StockDetail

InvNo       Varchar(50)
InvDate     DateTime
Quantity    Decimal(18,2)
Rate        Decimal(18,2)
Amount      Decimal(18,2)
Type        varchar(50) Purchase/Sale
```

I have two table for purchase and two table for sale. For some requirement i have to maintain purchase and sale table separately.

At the time of Purchase, I want to insert record to table like...

```
PurchaseMaster
PurchaseDetail
StockDetail
```

At the time of Sale I want to insert record to table like...

```
SaleMaster
SaleDetail
StockDetail
```

In both case i want to insert record to StockDetail table to maintain stock.

But how can i set primarykey and foreighkey relationship between PurchaseDetail, SaleDetail with StockDetail table?

Comment: The better question is why you have chosen this path. You are intentionally duplicating information - why? You can easily find the same information from the sale and purchase tables. You can make it "easier" to do so by creating a view that unions those tables.

Answer (score 0):

You cant set a foreign key to StockDetail to 2 tables unless you create 2 FK fields.

StockDetail

```
StockDetail_id                 -- PK  for StockDetail
InvNo_sales       Varchar(50)  -- Foreign Key to sales or null
InvNo_purchase    Varchar(50)  -- Foreign Key to purchase or null
InvDate     DateTime
Quantity    Decimal(18,2)
Rate        Decimal(18,2)
Amount      Decimal(18,2)
Type        varchar(50) Purchase/Sale
```

But the correct solution is put Sales and Purchase in the same table

```
InvNo       varchar(50) (PK)
TypeTransaction  int      -- 1 for sale 2 for purchase
InvDate     DateTime
NetAmount   decimal(18,2)

InvNo       varchar(50) (FK)
TypeTransaction  int      -- 1 for sale 2 for purchase
InvDate     DateTime
Quantity    decimal(18,2)
Rate        decimal(18,2)
Amount      decimal(18,2)
```